# API MercadoPago in RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, e-commerce

I'm trying to integrate API MercadoPago ( https://www.mercadopago.com.ar/developers/en/ ) , to my web . The web consists of sales of products and wish to include a payment option , which has necessarily to be through MercadoPago . I do not know where to start, I have no idea of how to implement it . There is some documentation or courses of this in ruby ? I searched but could not find . Please see the API.

Answer (score 0):

you could start to reading documentation api here

https://www.mercadopago.com.ar/developers/en/api-docs/

you'll need to install ruby sdk

```
gem install mercadopago-sdk
```

ruby sdk doc:

https://www.mercadopago.com.ar/developers/en/tools/sdk/server/ruby/

there is another gem, but if I were you, I would use the official sdk

https://rubygems.org/gems/mercadopago

That gem seems has documentation here

http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/mercadopago/2.2.1

Comment: thanks for answering. I'm reading the documentation , but still there are many things I do not understand . For example , where to put the code shown in the documents , like this:                                                          # Use your credentials
client_id = '1234'
client_secret = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'

mp_client = MercadoPago::Client.new(client_id, client_secret). Or how to call mercadopago.rb

Comment: You can create a new model called MercadoPago, and there in the initialize could manage your that code. and you will need to create a user on MP